# Class not found phonegap plugin android

Tags: phonegap-plugins

I've made a plugin for my android project, but I get the error `Error: Status=2 Message=Class not found`. I'm using another plugin from phonegap-plugins/android repository successfully. When I made my own I copied the files from the plugin that already works to get the function/method names etc. right. I have googled and looked "everywhere", but can't figure it out.

The javafile is called EmailSender.java, extends Plugin and is placed in `src/phonegap/plugins/emailSender`.
In my plugins.xml I have this line: 
`<plugin name="EmailSender" value="phonegap.plugins.emailSender.EmailSender"/>`

**emailsender.js**

```
var EmailSender = function() {
}

EmailSender.prototype.sendMail = function(day, time, email) {
    return PhoneGap.exec(null, null, 'emailSender', 'sendMail', [day, time, email]);
};

PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
    PhoneGap.addPlugin("emailSender", new EmailSender());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

just check out this link as it is sample for the intent plugin so by passing intent default chooser options will be pop up. please clarify more if you want other things.
https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/WebIntent